# Cannot include high-charts in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi i am trying to include highcharts in my vue cli code inside a component. But i am getting "Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?" For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option." in console.

I have installed the highcharts using the following commands

npm install --save highcharts

npm install highcharts-vue

Is there anything i am doing wrong or missing something ?

```
Home.vue

<template>
<div class="col-md-9 chartDiv">
  <h4 align='center'>{{ tableChart.title2 }}</h4>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {{tableChart.chartOption}}
    <div class="chart-size center-block">
      <highcharts name="highcharts" v-bind:options="tableChart.chartOption" 
        ref="highcharts" charttype="highchart"></highcharts>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'HomePage',
props: {
tableChart: {
  type: Object,
  required: false
}
},
data: function() {
return this.tableChart;
 }
};
</script>

App.vue

<template>
<div id="app">
<home-page v-bind:table-chart="tableData"></home-page>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.vue';
import tableData2018 from './dataSource.js';
export default {
 name: 'app',
 components: {
   HomePage
 },
 data: function() {
  return {
    years: [2018, 2019, 2020],
    tableData: {}
  }
 },
methods: {
 initReport: function() {
  this.tableData = JSON.parse(tableData2018);
  }
},
created: function() {
  this.initReport();
}
};
```

```
main.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
 render: h => h(App),
 }).$mount('#app');



dataSource.js
{"chartOption":{"chart":{"plotBorderWidth":1,"type":"bubble","zoomType":"xy"},"credits":{"enabled":true,"href":"#","position":{"align":"right","verticalAlign":"bottom","y":-10},"text":"www.highcharts.com"},"exporting":{"enabled":false,"filename":"exportChart","type":"image/svg+xml","url":"http://export.highcharts.com.","width":600},"legend":{"align":"center","enabled":0,"floating":false,"layout":"vertical","verticalAlign":"bottom","x":0,"y":0,"z":0},"plotOptions":{"series":{"dataLabels":{"enabled":true,"format":"{point.name}"}}},"series":[{"data":[{"description":"Name","name":"xcode","x":1.02,"y":577039,"z":4092}]}],"title":{"text":""},"tooltip":{"followPointer":false,"footerFormat":"</table>","headerFormat":"<table>","pointFormat":"<tr><thcolspan=2><h5>{point.description}</h5></th></tr><tr><th>AdjustedReadmissions/ExpectedReadmissions:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr><tr><th>ExpectedPenalty:</th><td>${point.y}</td></tr><tr><th>Index Admissions:</th><td>{point.z}</td></tr>","useHTML":1},"xAxis":{"gridLineWidth":1,"labels":{"format":"{value}"},"plotLines":[{"color":"black","dashStyle":"dot","value":1,"width":2,"zIndex":3}],"tickmarkPlacement":"on","title":{"text":"AdjustedReadmissions/ExpectedReadmissions"}},"yAxis":{"labels":{"format":"{value}"},"showFirstLabel":false,"title":{"text":"ExpectedPenalty"}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main.js file, you should import `highcharts-vue` and load it before you call `new Vue()`

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import HighchartsVue from "highcharts-vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(HighchartsVue);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/4p8xw74y9

Comment: Thanks, it works. i am trying to include bubble chart in highcharts but getting the error " Error in mounted hook: "Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17". It says "Highcharts Error #17
The requested series type does not exist
This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.". how to overcome this

Comment: You have to load `highcharts-more` module and initialize it. Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#importing-highcharts-modules. Import: `import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'` and initialize: `HighchartsMore(Highcharts);`. If you found my answer helpful, please upvote, thanks.